# How do I filter data in a mvc gridview using Start and End date?

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, linq

So I have a list of records in an mvc gridview, I want to be able to filter this list using the StartDate and EndDate using jquery ajax.

This is my Index ActionResult

```
    public ActionResult Index(DateTime StartDate, DateTime EndDate)
    {
        decimal MinCost = 1.99m;

        var Transactions = db.Sales.Where(x => x.UnitCost > MinCost && x.AddedOn > StartDate && x.AddedOn < EndDate).OrderByDescending(x => x.Person).ToList();

        return View(Transactions);
    }
```

This is my Jquery function where I am trying to call the Index ActionResult and pass the two dates.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">

        function FilterRecords(StartDate, EndDate) {
            var data = {
                StartDate: StartDate,
                EndDate: EndDate
            };
            $.ajax({
                type: 'GET',
                url: '@Url.Action("Index", "Records")',
                data: data,
                success: function (data) {
                    $('#Index').html(data);
                },
                error: function (error) {
                    alert(JSON.stringify(error));

                    cache: true;
                }
            })
        }

    </script>
```

These are the two date inputs

```
    <label>Select Start Date</label>
    <input type="date" name="StartDate" id="StartDate" />
    <label>Select End Date</label>
    <input type="date" name="EndDate" id="EndDate"  onclose="FilterRecords()" />
```

Comment: What is your actual problem? Rather than using `onclose`, I recommend you to put a button and handle `onclick="FilterRecords()"`, then pick value of both date pickers inside the function instead of passing as parameter.

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto My problem is passing those two date values to the jquery function and filtering the list in the Index ActionResult. I will try using a button and see if it works.

Comment: Remember if you want to use client-side script against button click event handler, use `<button type="button" ... />` and/or `preventDefault()` with `return false` to stop default submit behavior and execute the script instead. You can easily use `$('#StartDate').val()` and `$('#EndDate').val()` to retrieve both start and end dates.

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto Thank you, it worked. I used what you recommended above.